# RSA decryption with 2048 bit key is giving bad data for encrypted text of length 340 on windows server 2012 r2,while it is working fine on windows 8

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, windows-server-2012-r2, pkcs#1

```
  RSACryptoServiceProvider objRsaCrypto= new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
string xmlString = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>vafMwhQ1Z+zx1tpcUybDONf3M7IG8Xw6Q0eCsuWMRniqwUklnzndo9ExuAFC87oAywOcSSzSncLEgILxjiyNmnBe28whdDg+P1PJmDchmBIjzQKNpDIppOiaxGOUR8KqBwIMp24dZQtUqb9mElEEz5bOxZUwHLg2/fJ9bT+eE+VluHtYfuuS/nbhrvI6BHN2bm2CyITBAvT6loCm7mV/JZ0fT9nCsyn6rUsp+YCVbhrfMnyz9aW7NEkwncE7xz78LSIHaYgB19nPu5jkR6yUCLsNDV9wnOBjb1Xuh7NqTjt2yOAcH+Gt5ixukfKBROq67FlnQKZOa+mQNzkhytEeyw==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>4tDAYRgWNcyB5dCN7kF8QUa4ddiw6siEblGnjcFpdrQLyJxFvCZ7Jlc/59Wmr8B/1G06coRla5NLBCtvh/Itovacfp00wNif5pBb/Tp9+quw5/GGSu/4/K/Ke0wQuhHdWNjzAriNxbpCRWD/EgzNngWS8KlufdymZyju6AWyEZk=</P><Q>1g8B7fQ3SMDZ2EyaiSscchj3lshJx9VR8EAN70aipu45LRsOWuHH7wTkfqp1LuB06LyCr7XLMwUQYrBM8mJOhtxsiissXe+Phw1kcXJo6hBrCPgfSKSkuHT8iR7OgZbzYA8zwMmr+m2WOuDsgxrQcb+hRVdC1QODqFb8C08YegM=</Q><DP>vW5Zbf4e9pmx142CLH3219HH12y9/aiwqi56QPNLML+Yo9iYiVaePdxa3DZdO6YLXRBI40HeLqVa3sWkJadHJDbRZxHG8FU73uWsXmcOtl/UpTLb1RRtICV1d9qEkdK/yiePdjNK/Nvd43HqNloJFLRVD7iCNo4lUD0ooxG2sek=</DP><DQ>BCeWaf/rcsYLdF9IQJFNpAlIBO0uQWqqhHc5zgMY9RR6l52G0czADKuTo8G7NIW2vy2pe6+TmhHnF4NEew/dZlCw6p2b5tbXek+QO4N09dYLvcjTEp3fdJUQsbifWXSMlLi20G8Zn2qxF8N107WZhhuqDaZ77ZZ737CQg8etOfE=</DQ><InverseQ>xEjq9mm61gofysxxgM6SnX5TQ5Lnpq0AvnsRBhQaatiGm8i+VnznMpk8zJgn/AspaYS62bFC/UdCd/b2VyXgZfBC/L1NdkIUNyOVAxNKhf95C4uQFFxe90RfuZjbbClFbm/tU7RmycHqciPXViI35tToF1CXMJsxd7q6M2iaXKc=</InverseQ><D>HVnfO/gBreRDJzOjDzFUDDOMK+F05qGJqMjj5sjUtUFOd9xYqLQ9Y3FoJuh3Ep4qKkEUSlTYAZdXbuYU+SJXBdw3KgAE+2YK6CUQ8XAy0ESaastm3U7wF/fxn8wjchmj07LS/4RwoycmQqD+7H3CZ1gZBwYILKGrzRBere4nCj/1i5LTbfweAMUo85KMfZDbGChlJUhd4vNiRPGmOeKCT1/xDAw/3ZKfUbhUjzBxg/1PThhLtv2wYEdkLpUq1RZmlJACtDD++fkt9x19UecfMpX7NmI43WLoc1x7ydtinrIO0b0NhFStXAPEQXlYyE4JvOSqIxJIbb/E7Vl5okVxOQ==</D></RSAKeyValue>";//my private key
  objRsaCrypto.FromXmlString(xmlString);
string cyphertextyear ="mell442PqhwZRDvAVawKhtspVWFsVG6x/6v7BzcaDvOFWImXOiq3hCZq6N0i7UpCkV8YVLLS/LTarWrSgrqskfQnIwA+inZIhfZLm3odUrYpBCMXJh9Y7s+6ugqiwpMu1xap9LBqhP7LdChwIV0c7GimgZKVVk7mZHBgmVOHRSx61RAx6HDkc0F7dfjBR+jUQR08knu4MUUNx7xQ6pSkg1MyTwrX4upMoodccBwni+cUFZWmIeEHazMMd2r6PkuwMvHkueFm0B4UsWnsqHtjgQuU5zmGx9rWpDIyDCKNTvWkTyB1lUrhpNk6qqeFZXVPPTsxfKcA0Pp2oz6ZF4ir";//my cypher text

 byte[] bytesCypherText = Convert.FromBase64String(cyphertextyear);
 byte[] bytesPlainTextData = objRsaCrypto.Decrypt(bytesCypherText, false);
  string strDecryptedVal = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesPlainTextData);
```

I am using RSACryptoServiceProvider and decryption is working fine in windows 8 but failing in windows server 2012 r2 with below exception

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Bad Data.
>
> at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32
>   hr)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.DecryptKey(SafeKeyHandle
>   pKeyContext, Byte[] pbEncryptedKey, Int32 cbEncryptedKey, Boolean
>   fOAEP, ObjectHandleOnStack ohRetDecryptedKey)
>   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(Byte[]
>   rgb, Boolean fOAEP)at

Comment: @ArtjomB thanks for responding. I have included the private key and cyphertext.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496793/rsa-encryption-getting-bad-length

Comment: @WazeAndroid data is not long..

Comment: Perhaps it is necessary to know which .Net version is installed.

Comment: By the way, I found two online c# code execution sites where the [first decrypts correctly](http://ideone.com/y7c0bD) and the [second fails with bad data](http://csharppad.com/gist/fe84d5de8177e1884de0cbadb47b6dc7).

Comment: @ArtjomB.Thanks for responding. application is using .Net 4.0.

Comment: @user3459002, were you able to resolve this by any chance? I am also facing similar issue, but with 1024 bit, the decryption works fine in Windows 7, but fails in Windows 10 & Windows Server 2012. Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Your ciphertext is too short.

The length of `bytesCypherText` is 255, but your 2048-bit key produces a 256-byte response.

It seems that previous versions of Windows accepted too short and effectively prepended the value with extra zero bytes, and that they stopped doing that.  (Most likely the original CAPI providers had the behavior of accepting "too short", but they have since been replaced with calls into the same backend that drives CNG; and it probably only accepts correctly sized data.)

If your ciphertext base64 were

```
AJnpZeONj6ocGUQ7wFWsCobbKVVhbFRusf+r+wc3Gg7zhViJlzoqt4QmaujdIu1KQpFfGFSy0vy02q1q
0oK6rJH0JyMAPop2SIX2S5t6HVK2KQQjFyYfWO7PuroKosKTLtcWqfSwaoT+y3QocCFdHOxopoGSlVZO
5mRwYJlTh0UsetUQMehw5HNBe3X4wUfo1EEdPJJ7uDFFDce8UOqUpINTMk8K1+LqTKKHXHAcJ4vnFBWV
piHhB2szDHdq+j5LsDLx5LnhZtAeFLFp7Kh7Y4ELlOc5hsfa1qQyMgwijU71pE8gdZVK4aTZOqqnhWV1
Tz07MXynAND6dqM+mReIqw==
```

You'll likely have better luck.

Alternatively:

```
if (bytesCypherText.Length * 8 < objRsaCrypto.KeySize)
{
    byte[] tmp = new byte[objRsaCrypto.KeySize / 8];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(
        bytesCypherText,
        0,
        tmp,
        tmp.Length - bytesCypherText.Length,
        bytesCypherText.Length);

    bytesCypherText = tmp;
}

byte[] bytesPlainTextData = objRsaCrypto.Decrypt(bytesCypherText, false);
```